# installing openmpi on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, mpi

I am trying to instlal OpenMPI on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS following this [guide](http://particlephysicsandcode.com/2012/11/04/installing-open-mpi-1-6-3-ubuntu-12-04-fedora/)

When I run the command `sudo apt-get install -y autotools-dev g++ build-essential openmpi1.5-bin openmpi1.5-doc libopenmpi1.5-dev` I get the error messages

```
E: Unable to locate package openmpi1.5-doc
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'openmpi1.5-doc'
E: Unable to locate package libopenmpi1.5-dev~
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libopenmpi1.5-dev~'
```

Why is that? I tried on Ubuntu 12.04, there it worked fine.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't think I understand? Sorry, what do you mean..

Comment: @Rinzwind I get the same error after adding `universe`

Answer (score 14):

The version of openmpi in the 14.04 repository is 1.6. The packages you probably need to install `openmpi-bin` `openmpi-doc` `libopenmpi-dev`.

Generally, it's not recommended to install a specific release-numbered version of packages: there should be a package that always *depends* on the current version for the release, i.e.

```
$ apt-cache depends libopenmpi-dev
libopenmpi-dev
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libopenmpi1.6
  Depends: openmpi-common
  Depends: libibverbs-dev
  Depends: libhwloc-dev
  Conflicts: libopenmpi-dev
  Conflicts: libopenmpi-dev:i386
  Conflicts: openmpi-bin
  Conflicts: openmpi-bin:i386
  Conflicts: 
  Conflicts: 
  Conflicts: libopenmpi-dev:i386
```