# mpif.h not found error [install openmpi]

Tags: fortran, mpi

I was trying to install openpi on ubuntu. I have an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (64 bit) desktop.
I installed openmpi using

> sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-common openmpi-doc libopenmpi2 libopenmpi-dev openssh-client openssh-server

Then, in the .bashrc, I have added the following two lines:

> echo export PATH="$PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/bin" >> /home/$USER/.bashrc
>
> echo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/$USER/.openmpi/lib/" >> /home/$USER/.bashrc

After that, I used [dartmouth hello world mpi](https://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Erc/classes/intro_mpi/hello_world_ex.html)  to write a small program, compile it and run it to check that the openmpi installation is OK by typing `gfortran ubuntu.f90`

which leads to the following error

> ubuntu.f90:2: Error: Can't open included file 'mpif.h'

the code in ubuntu.f90 :

```
program hello
include 'mpif.h'
integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
print*, 'node', rank, ': Hello world'
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end
```

I have tried [installing libblacs-mpi-dev](https://askubuntu.com/a/1032572/707756) as in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1032568/707756). This [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/612822/707756) does not seem relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include a C-style header file in a Fortran program, you need to use a C-style pre-processor directive

```
#include <mpif.h>
```

rather than a native Fortran `include` statement, and then tell `gfortran` to run the pre-processor by adding the `-cpp` command-line switch (or change the source file suffix to upper-case `F90` which causes the pre-processor to be run by default). See for example

- [including a c/c++ header file in fortran subroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14630588)

However including `mpif.h` is apparently deprecated, and instead you should probably use the MPI *module*, and compile your program using `mpif90` instead of invoking `gfortran` directly.

- [Fortran Support Through the mpif.h Include File](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node411.htm)

Ex.

```
$ cat ubuntu.f90 
program hello
use mpi
integer rank, size, ierror, tag, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

call MPI_INIT(ierror)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierror)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierror)
print*, 'node', rank, ': Hello world'
call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
end

$ mpif90 ubuntu.f90

$ ./a.out 
 node           0 : Hello world
```

FWIW, your changes to `PATH` and `LD_LIBRAY_PATH` likely have no effect since you have installed `openmpi` into system directories using `apt`

Comment: Basically, I am an idiot.  I should have been running 'mpif90 ubuntu.f90 -o ubuntu.out', followed by 'mpirun -n 8 ubuntu.out'